# How to set SendGrid custom Unsubscribe HTML body?

Tags: sendgrid

I've got Subscription Tracking **ON**, in "**UNSUBSCRIBE CONTENT - HTML BODY**" section - my custom HTML text. But in sent emails I'm getting standard "*Unsubscribe From This List | Manage Email Preferences*" footer, which is not my custom HTML content. Can't understand what I am missing here.

Comment: You should provide an example of the email send request.

Comment: This custom footer should be declared somewhere in personalization? I'm reading the docs and it says: 'If you would like to place the unsubscribe text somewhere else in the email content, you can do so by placing an unsubscribe tag. You would need to define this tag here. If no tag is found, we will simply place the unsubscribe information at the bottom of the email.' Nothing about any customization of sent message.

Comment: Did you get to solve this? I have the same issue. If I don't send the custom unsubscribe tag, the html unsubscribe contend should be shown. Instead, I get those same links you mention :-/

Comment: No, sorry, I no longer work with SendGrid.

Answer (score 7):

That setting refers to the global unsubscribe link. The "Unsubscribe From This List" link is a result of having unsubscribe groups configured. This page documents fairly well how you can replace the default links with your own.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/index-suppressions/

For example, a custom unsubscribe link in your template could look like this:

```
<a href="<%asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url%>">unsubscribe</a>
```

Your template engine may URL encode the tag, so be sure to keep the raw tag intact. The default links will then disappear.